# Multiple clicks starting multiple events

Tags: jquery

I want the keydown event to trigger after a click has been done, but the problem is that it triggers after multiple clicks have been done. For example, clicking 5 times and pressing the left arrow key once will alert 5 times, because somehow in a way I don't understand, the clicks stack up in some kind of queue.

What I want is the alert to be triggered only once per key press. So, no matter how many clicks have been done, I will get only 1 alert per key press.

Can someone explain to me what is happening behind and how can I fix this?

http://jsfiddle.net/aa99j/1/

JS

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#a').click(function () {

        $(document).keydown(function (key) {
            switch (parseInt(key.which, 10)) {
                // Left arrow key pressed
                case 37:
                    alert('test');
                    break;
            }
        });
    });
});
```

HTML+CSS

```
<div id="a"> </div>
#a {
    background-color:blue;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
}
```

Comment: You are binding events on every click. So when you click mutiple times events are binded multiple times. http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/fwaA4/

Comment: @Satpal Instead of that you could have suggested `.one()`

Comment: Every time you click you add a new event handler for the keydown event, so the function for the keydown event fires as many times as you've bound the event handler, which is bound every time you click, get it !

Comment: And where are the handlers...put? In a queue? It took me ages to even discover this was the problem, maybe I'm missing a basic understandment.

Comment: You could think of it as a queue if that helps you, but they are really just "added", every single one, each one firing etc. It's not like if you add the same event handler twice, the last one overwrites the first one etc. they all stick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every time a click event happens, you are running the code that binds the keydown function. Clicking 5 times binds it 5 times.

To avoid it, you can use some sort of a flag that gets set the first time, and subsequently ignore it if the flag is set

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var flag = false;
    $('#a').click(function () {

        if (flag) {
            return false;
        }

        flag = true;

        $(document).keydown(function (key) {
            switch (parseInt(key.which, 10)) {
                // Left arrow key pressed
                case 37:
                    alert('test');
                    break;
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#a').one("click", function () {

        $(document).keydown(function (key) {
            switch (parseInt(key.which, 10)) {
                // Left arrow key pressed
                case 37:
                    alert('test');
                    break;
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: -1: This may answer the question, but not explaining what youve changed (and why) means the answer is almost useless to the OP and everyone else

Comment: @Satpal - It takes a moment to type ;)

Comment: Theres not that much code for your eyes to do a quick compare!

Comment: @MrPeeps, Still a little explanation makes much easier to read. Jamiec is only trying to make you a better answer-er. take criticism on chin

Comment: The problem here is that this accepts only 1 click. I want to be able to click multiple times on the div, for instance.

Answer (score 1):

Every time you clicked a tag it will binded keydown event , so you have to unbind the key down event

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#a').click(function () {
        $(document).off("keydown");
        $(document).on("keydown", function (key) {
            switch (parseInt(key.which, 10)) {
                // Left arrow key pressed
                case 37:
                    alert('test');
                    break;
            }
        });
    });
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/aa99j/8/)**

Or use

```
 var isclickA = false;
 $('#a').click(function () {
    isclickA = true;
 });

$(document).on("keydown", function (key) {
      if (isclickA) {
        switch (parseInt(key.which, 10)) {
            // Left arrow key pressed
            case 37:
                alert('test');
                break;
        }
    }
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/aa99j/11/)